# Activity's incapability with androidx

Tags: android, android-activity, androidx, appcompatactivity, android-fragment-manager

I encountered to a problem related to Activity's getFragmentManager() incossitency with androidx.FragmentManager.

So I have the following method:

```
public void myMethod(Activity activity) {
    /**
     * do some staff here
     */
    
    //now we should open a DialogFragment
    new MyCustomDialogFragment().show((activity).getFragmentManager(), MyCustomDialogFragment.TAG);
    
}
```

and here I'm getting error `"Can not resolve method show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)`.

All these because my `DialogFragment` is from `androidx.fragment.app` package when `Activity`'s `getFragmentManager()` returns `FragmentManager` from `android.app` package.

I see 2 options to solve this.

1. Change dependency of `DialogFragment`, and use the one from `android.app`
2. Change `myMethod()` signature to receive `AppCompatActivity` (from androidx) instead of `Activity` and call `getSupportedFragmentManager()`.

First solution is not good as I want to keep using androidx classes everywhere possible. Second is also has drawbacks despite of AppCompatAcivitity is a best practice.

**Question is** : Is there a way to keep using androidx dependency and having `Activity` type parameter inside `myMethod()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FragmentActivity` (from androidx) instead of `Activity` as the argument type in `myMethod()` and call `getSupportFragmentManager()` to get the `FragmentManager` on it. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Using FragmentActivity seems better than AppCompatActivity as it is super class, but again is not good enough as I don't want to limit my method users with the activity subclasses.  Logic is this, I have Activity class, which has getFragmentManager() method and I want to use that with androidx. The incapability issue is kind of unacceptable here.